# Infinite reboot loop "System BootOrder not found" after Windows 10 install and Ubuntu install

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, grub, uefi

After wiping a disk, installing Windows 10, then installing Ubuntu with Grub, I experienced an infinite reboot loop with this error message (displayed less than 0.5 second, hard to read!):

> System BootOrder not found. [...]

**How to solve this infinite reboot loop problem after installing Ubuntu?**

Note: The BIOS is set on "UEFI only" startup mode.

Note 2: This [question/answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747/system-bootorder-not-found) did not help, I don't have "Select an UEFI as trusted" in my BIOS options, all the other answers seem relevant to this specific Acer TravelMate, but it did not help in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I lost one hour trying lots of things, unsuccessfully, and reading various questions/answers and other blog posts, I post a solution here with the "Answer your own question" feature, it might save time for future readers too.

- Boot with a Ubuntu live USB
- In terminal do:

  ```
    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/   # let's say sda1 is the EFI partition
    sudo ls /mnt/EFI/    # this will show the different boot systems
    sudo cp /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
    sudo umount /dev/sda1
    sudo reboot
  ```
- Done!

Source (in French), it was not easy to find: https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2011932&p=2